# can i see real time javascript events like ajax calls in firebug?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio

So when I do an ajax POST I can see the thing firing in firebug, I can see the spinning icon as it's running, a finished icon when it's done. I can see results or errors and whatnot, you all know the deal.

Is there a way to get it to show me every javascript event as it fires? So if I have something like this in my windows onload:

```
defaultJs.LoadImages();
defaultJs.CheckAccount(username);
vendorsJs.UpdateSearch();
```

I would ideally see each of those happening, or be able to step through them similar to how you would step through CS files while you're attached to the WWW process with F10 and F11 and all that.

My problem is how long it takes tracking through another person's code when I'm tasked with finishing the work of another developer that's been moved to another project. I basically have to do what I described manually reading the code, or set up a ton of console.logs to try and force this sort of information into something I can read.

I'm hoping firebug has some feature I haven't enabled, or there's a program like fiddler (where you see things loading realtime) that'll do it for me.

Sorry if this is a repeat question, I wasn't able to find an answer that worked for me after some searching. I appreciate any time anyone commits to helping me out here. Have a good day yall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can debug the JS code using FireBug

[image]

http://getfirebug.com/javascript

Comment: thanks so much, it won't let me accept your answer just yet but i will do so in a few minutes when it does!